# How to convert a string that a user typed in a dialog box (JOptionPane) into a enum?

Tags: java, string, enums

I have a enum for gender.

```
public enum Gender {
  Male("M"), Female("F");
  private String value;

  Gender(String value){
      this.value = value;
  }


  public String getValue() {
      return value;
 }
}
```

This enum is a constructor of my class.

```
class People {
   private String name;
   private int id;
   private int age;
   private Gender x;
}
```

Then I'm trying to create a new object of this class from the user, a user type a name, id, age and gender. I'm using the dialog box JOptionPane.
The line I'm getting a error is this one.

```
 public class AppPeople {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Gender gender1; //I tried declaring String gender1
                   //To get the answer/input below, but didn't work.
   gender1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type Male or Female");
   People p1 = new People(name, id, age, Gender1);
   }
}
```

All the others fields are working from the dialog box, name, id and age. This one that is a enum isn't working. I had to declare id and age string to use it on dialog box, so the answer typed I got into strings variables and converted it to integer, to match the constructor of the class. I tried declaring a new string to get the input from dialog box and convert it to enum but still didn't work. The only field left is this one to convert a string to enum. Does anyone know what can I do to fix or maybe a new solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
 gender1 = Gender.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type Male or Female").toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

just se method of each enum

```
Gender.valueOf("yourString")
```